# Set first cell to highlighted on view's load

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UISplitViewController.  When the app launches initially, the detail view is showing the detail data for the first row.  However, the cell in the table is not highlighted, since it hasn't been selected yet.  How can I set it to selected by default when the app loads initially?

I added this to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but its not highlighting.  It highlights fine when I actually select a cell.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    cell.selected = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)selectFirstRow {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    // optional:
    // [self tableView:myTable willSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [myTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    // optional:
    // [self tableView:myTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Then call `[self selectFirstRow];` wherever you need to.